# Как можно избавиться от длинной строки в css

Tags: css

Добрый день, подскажите как можно сократить код в примере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например:

```
#user-list (.fa-arrow-up,.fa-check,.fa-refresh ,.fa-repeat) {
    color: red
}
```

без повторения `#user-list`

Comment: Вариант с препроцессорами CSS не рассматривали?

Comment: мне кажется, я где-то встречал запись на обычном css, без использования препроцессора.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стандарт CSS не предполагает какое-либо сокращение указанных в вопросе строк. В частности, вложенные стили в CSS недопустимы. Но проблема имеет решение и решением являются препроцессоры CSS. Одним из них является [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), допускающий, в том числе, вложение селекторов. На `LESS` Ваш пример будет выглядеть так:

```
#user-list {
    .fa-arrow-up, .fa-check, .fa-refresh, .fa-repeat {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

После обработки данного кода препроцессором будет получен требуемый CSS-код.

Answer (score 3):

Для таких целей есть CSS препроцессоры. Например [SASS](http://sass-lang.com), [LESS](http://lesscss.org) или [Stylus](https://learnboost.github.io/stylus/)

Ваш пример будет выглядеть на **SASS**:

```
#user-list
  .fa-arrow-up, .fa-check, .fa-refresh, .fa-repeat
    color: red
```

На **LESS**:

```
#user-list {
    .fa-arrow-up, .fa-check, .fa-refresh, .fa-repeat {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Лично я использовал `LESS` и `SASS` и для меня удобнее `LESS`, т.к. привычное использование скобок и точек с запятой в конце строки, то есть можно спокойно взять готовый `CSS` и вставить в `LESS`. С `SASS` сложнее, т.к. `CSS` код не вставить просто так в `SASS` без использования сервисов специальных, но зато выглядит компактнее.